# In shell scripting, what does .[!.]* mean?

Tags: bash, gnu-coreutils

A command that prints a list of files and folders in the current directory along with their total sizes is `du -sh *`. That command alone doesn't, however, list hidden files or folders. I found a solution for a command that does correctly list the hidden files and folders along with the rest: `du -sh .[!.]* *`. Although it works perfectly, the solution was provided as-is, without any explanation.

What is the meaning of `.[!.]*`, exactly? How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a globbing pattern that basically tells bash to find all files starting with a `.`, followed by any character but a  `.`and containing any character after that.

See [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for a great explanation of bash globbing patterns.

Comment: So it's matching all files/folders prefixed with a `.` while implicitly excluding the paths `.` and `..`. Very clever!

Comment: yes, I thought so too :)  It's a good trick. Can you point the page where you found it? there might be other things to learn ...  And I really recommend to read the page I pointed too. The guy who wrote it knows his bash.

Comment: It's about ten-fifteen comments from the top here: http://www.ducea.com/2006/05/14/tip-how-to-sort-folders-by-size-with-one-command-line-in-linux/

Comment: Note that now we can use `du -sh (...) | sort -hr`, we don't have to use `du -s (...) | sort -nr` since `sort -h` sorts by human-readable byte counts. I'm not sure that flag was around a decade ago when that conversation was written.

Answer (score 3):

`.` - match a `.`, prefix of hidden file

`[!.]` - match any character, as long as it is not a `.`, [see ref](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)

`*` - any number of characters

so this pattern means match files starts with `.` but not `..`

Answer (score 0):

`.[!.]*` the meaning is any file or directory name start with `.` but not following with `.`, so it will include all hidden files and directories under current directory but exclude parent directory.

Because this behaviour is decided by shell glob pattern. So you can use `ls .[!.]*` to see what actually get in your shell environment.

BTW, you can turn `dotglob` on in your shell to simplify your `du` command.

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ du -sh *
$ shopt -u dotglob
```

From bash manual

> **dotglob** If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results of pathname expansion.